# XCode: No visibile @interface for (xxx) declares the selector (xxx)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to add functionality to add an attachment to an sms message.  The following

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments]) {
    if(args[@"attachments"]) {
        NSString *attachmentData = [RCTConvert NSString:args[@"attachment"][@"data"]];
        NSString *typeIdentifier = @"kUTTypeJPEG";
        NSString *attchmentName = [RCTConvert NSString:args[@"attachment"][@"name"]];

        [mcvc addAttachmentData:attachmentData typeIdentifier:typeIdentifier fileName:attachmentName]
    }
}
```

throws this error:

> No Visible @interface for 'MFMessageComposeViewController' declares the selector 'addAttachmentData:attachmentData typeIdentifier:typeIdentifier fileName:attachmentName'

Comment: This is why you always want to use Xcode's autocomplete. It avoid typos like this.

Comment: I'm very new to all of this, so that tip is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename:`
You have spelled your method wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's been killing me.

Answer (score 2):

The correct name of the method is `addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename:`.

See the lower case "n" in the last parameter label.

Comment: Much appreciated Nikolai, you just saved me a lot of frustration.